# What is the escape code for square brackets in a C# code snippet?

Tags: c#, escaping, code-snippets

trying to write a VS2010 C# code snippet that has a closing square bracket as part of new object array assignment, basically so:

```
<Code Language="CSharp">
<![CDATA[public void $MethodName$($parameters$)
{
    if(InvokeRequired)
    {
        ZPICD icdzp = new ZPICD($MethodName);
        Invoke(icdzp, new object[] { });
    }
    else
    {
        $selected$
    }
}
public delegate void ZPICD();]]]>
</Code>
```

doesn't look like there is a lot on the subject, both bing and google are giving weak results for searches like:
escape square brackets in C# snippet
C# snippet square brackets
C# code snippet square brackets

Comment: It's supposed to end with `]]>`. I see one extra `]` there.

Comment: You are right, I am also missing a $ at the end of the second $MethodName$ replacement token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for square bracket escape codes, the parser looks to be keeping track of the square bracket depth level through the body of the snippet.  The problem was a missing replacement token delineator.

Comment: The only situation where a problem could occur, is if the C# code were to contain the exact three-character sequence `]]>` with no spaces. So if the code had something like `if (list[indices[i]]>threshold) { ... }` that would be a problem. But with a space inserted, there would be no problem. See also [Wikipedia: CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Syntax_and_interpretation).

Comment: Neat, thanks.  I think maybe that close token should have been defined by whatever working group as ]CDATA]> to help avoid that totally unlikely ambiguity